# How to enable extensions API in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I'd like to try out the new [Ingress](http://kubernetes.io/v1.1/docs/user-guide/ingress.html) resource available in Kubernetes 1.1 in Google Container Engine (GKE). But when I try to create for example the following resource:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-ingress
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: testsvc
    servicePort: 80
```

using:

```
$ kubectl create -f test-ingress.yaml
```

I end up with the following error message:

```
error: could not read an encoded object from test-ingress.yaml: API version "extensions/v1beta1" in "test-ingress.yaml" isn't supported, only supports API versions ["v1"]
error: no objects passed to create
```

When I run `kubectl version` it shows:

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"0", GitVersion:"v1.0.7", GitCommit:"6234d6a0abd3323cd08c52602e4a91e47fc9491c", GitTreeState:"clean"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"1", GitVersion:"v1.1.1", GitCommit:"92635e23dfafb2ddc828c8ac6c03c7a7205a84d8", GitTreeState:"clean"}
```

But I seem to have the latest `kubectl` component installed since running `gcloud components update kubectl` just gives me:

```
All components are up to date.
```

So how do I enable the `extensions/v1beta1` in Kubernetes/GKE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your client (kubectl) doesn't support the new ingress resource because it hasn't been updated to 1.1 yet. This is mentioned in the [Google Container Engine release notes](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/release-notes#november_12_2015):

> The packaged kubectl is version 1.0.7, consequently new Kubernetes 1.1
>   APIs like autoscaling will not be available via kubectl until next
>   week's push of the kubectl binary.

along with the solution (download the newer binary manually).